# I have to convert the list of the objects to the object and vice versa in Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I have to convert the list of objects to the Event object and vice versa. I need it for the Room Database to store data from web. I created two converters, but they don't work. Converters class is set in database, data from web works well, I can download one object from the list, so there is no problem with an api and database.

Converters:

```
public class Converters {

@TypeConverter
public static ArrayList<Event> fromEvent(String event) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList>() {}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(event, listType);
}

@TypeConverter
public static String fromList(ArrayList<Event> events) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(events);
    return json;
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
 private void getEvents() {
    eventsViewModel.getEvents().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Event events) {
            if (events == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "EVENTS NULL");
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "EVENTS OK");
            }

            List<Event> events1 = (List) events;
            adapter.setEvents(events1);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

I am trying here parse Object events to the Event list but there is an error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.data.model.Event cannot be cast to java.util.List

Maybe I can't convert an object itself and I have to create another POJO and then put Event POJO to them as a list?

Repository:

```
public class EventRepository {

private final EventsApi apiInterface;
private EventDao eventDao;

@Inject
public EventRepository(EventsApi apiInterface, EventDao eventDao) {
    this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
    this.eventDao = eventDao;
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<Event>> fetchEvents() {

    final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Event>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    apiInterface.getEvents().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Event>> call, Response<ArrayList<Event>> response) {
            data.setValue(response.body());
                persistFetchedEvents(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Event>> call, Throwable t) {
            data.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    return data;

}

public LiveData<List<Event>> getEvents() {
    initEvents();
    return eventDao.getEvents();
}

private void persistFetchedEvents(List<Event> events) {
    new InsertEventsAsyncTask(eventDao).execute(events);
}

private static class InsertEventsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Event>, Void, Void> {
    private EventDao eventDao;

    private InsertEventsAsyncTask(EventDao eventDao) {
        this.eventDao = eventDao;
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    @Override
    protected final Void doInBackground(List<Event>... events) {
        eventDao.insertAll(events);
        return null;
    }
}

private void initEvents() {
    if (isFetchEventsNeeded(ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(1))) {
        fetchEvents();
    }
}

private Boolean isFetchEventsNeeded(ZonedDateTime lastfetchTime) {
    ZonedDateTime thirtyMinutesAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30);
    return lastfetchTime.isBefore(thirtyMinutesAgo);
}

}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
 public interface EventDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void updateEvent(Event event);

@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE idKey = 0")
LiveData<Event> getEvents();
}
```

Event:

```
@Entity(tableName = "events")
```

@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
public class Event {

```
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("subtitle")
@Expose
private String subtitle;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("imageUrl")
@Expose
private String imageUrl;
@SerializedName("videoUrl")
@Expose
private String videoUrl;

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
private int idKey = 0;

public Event(int id, String title, String subtitle, String date, String imageUrl, String videoUrl) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.date = date;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}

public int getIdKey() {
    return idKey;
}

public void setIdKey(int idKey) {
    this.idKey = idKey;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSubtitle() {
    return subtitle;
}

public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getVideoUrl() {
    return videoUrl;
}

public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}
}
```

Comment: Saying **they don't work** explains little. Please read [Help Centre - Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide an explanation of what **they don't work** actually is, (if crashing then include a stack-trace). You should also provide the context (e.g. code as a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: @beginner992 can you add the code for how you are saving and retrieving Events from your Local Database

Comment: @Networks are you mean Repository?

Comment: Yes the Repository and the Dao

Comment: @Networks I just pasted.

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassCastException` is being thrown because you are trying to cast an `Event` object into a list. Make sure your `eventsViewModel.getEvents()` returns `LiveData<ArrayList<Event>>` instead of `LiveData<Event>`.

Change the return type of `getEvents()` in `EventDao` from `LiveData<Event>` to `LiveData<ArrayList<Event>>`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE idKey = 0")
LiveData<ArrayList<Event>> getEvents();
```

Also your call to your ApiInterface returns a single event. Make sure it returns a list of `Events`. Then you can persist them all and your `LiveData<ArrayList<Event>>` from `eventDao.getEvents()` will update with your newly persisted list of `Event` objects.

**EDIT**
Per your request I'm adding an example

In your fragment

```
private void getEvents() {
    eventsViewModel.getEvents().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Event> events) {
            if (events == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "EVENTS NULL");
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "EVENTS OK");
            }

            adapter.setEvents(events);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

In the Repository

```
public class EventRepository {

private final EventsApi apiInterface;
private EventDao eventDao;

@Inject
public EventRepository(EventsApi apiInterface, EventDao eventDao) {
    this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
    this.eventDao = eventDao;
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<Event>> fetchEvents() {

    final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Event>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    apiInterface.getEvents().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Event>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Event>> call, Response<ArrayList<Event>> response) {

                data.postValue(response.body());
                persistFetchedEvents(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Event>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    return data;
}

public LiveData<List<Event>> getEvents() {
    initEvents();
    return eventDao.getEvents();
}

private void persistFetchedEvents(List<Event> events) {
    new InsertEventsAsyncTask(eventDao).execute(events);
}

private static class InsertEventsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Event>, Void, Void> {
    private EventDao eventDao;

    private InsertEventsAsyncTask(EventDao eventDao) {
        this.eventDao = eventDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<Event>... events) {
        Event[] eventArray = events[0].toArray(new Event[events[0].size()]);
        eventDao.insertAll(eventArray);
        return null;
    }
}

private void initEvents() {
    if (isFetchEventsNeeded(ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(1))) {
        fetchEvents();
    }
}

private Boolean isFetchEventsNeeded(ZonedDateTime lastfetchTime) {
    ZonedDateTime thirtyMinutesAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30);
    return lastfetchTime.isBefore(thirtyMinutesAgo);
}

}
```

In your dao(I added a new method to insertAll)

```
@Dao
 public interface EventDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(Event... events);

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void updateEvent(Event event);

@Query("SELECT * FROM events")
LiveData<List<Event>> getEvents();
}
```

**You will need to change the return type of `eventsViewModel.getEvents()` to `LiveData<List<Event>>` and `apiInterface.getEvents()` to `Call<ArrayList<Event>>`**

Comment: I did as you wished and there is a problem with set response.body() from fetchEvents to the persistedEvents: Inconvertible types Arraylist to Event. I am saving there only one object and then I set Arraylist. There also need to set Arraylist? I have already used converters in the Kotlin and there I save and get object. Here is little different.

Comment: You need to loop through the Arraylist in response.body() and use persistFetchedEvent() to save each event in the response.body().

Comment: I just did as you wrote and it seems to be right, but I have an error: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
I have the Entity in the Event class, and I also set there Converters class. In logs before crash I see the data, so your solution is gut, but there is problem with Room annotation.

Comment: Can you update your question with your Event class?

Comment: Done I also set in Dao list in insertAll in this way. List<Event>... Without dots I had red line.

Comment: I pasted the repository after the changes

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the doInBackground() and the insertAll() function

Comment: Update the insertAll() function too

Comment: In InsertEventsAsyncTask: AsyncTask<Event>, Void, Void> are red underlined: Wrong type of arguments 1; required: 3 
In doInBackground events are also red: Cannot resolve the symbol ''events''.
:/

Comment: It works, but it shows only one object from the list in logs and in recyclerview. I changed the number of database and there is still just one.

Comment: This is because of the your room query in getEvents(). Remove "WHERE idKey = 0" from the query.

Comment: Still same. In logs I see different number of list size. Then was 0, is 1 now.

Comment: Then you should check your response.body() to verify the number of events coming from your API. You can use breakpoints or log the size of the list your API returns.

Comment: response.body() is fine, there is 16 objects. There is some problem with Room. AsyncTask is terrible...

Comment: Ok it works! In Event class I set PrimaryKey as autoGenerate = true and deleted value 0 from idKey. But there is small error. I have bottom navigate and if I go to the another fragment and return to the older one the data is saved one more time and instead of 16 objects I see 32.

Comment: Set the id variable in Event Class as the PrimaryKey so Room can use that to know whether to Add or replace existing events when inserting new rows. Also all primary keys need to have the @NonNull annotation

Comment: Glad it works accept answer so others may benefit from it.

Comment: Wow! It works! You are amazing! :))) Thank you so much for so much help!